# hyperspectral image processing

Tags: python, pixel, satellite-image

I have an hyperspectral image, the value now is pixel intensity, how to convert it to reflectance value using Python, I need to calculate NDVI.

I don't have any experiment with processing hyperspectral image before.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.